# c# how to passing functions as string to methods

Tags: c#, function

Is it possible to pass a function (like let's say sin() ) via string and then use it as int?

Like:  (main idea only)

```
public int getfunc(String func)
{
   return res_of(func)
}
```

I tried playing around with string of "Math.sin(0)"
but couldn't print the 0...

I could predefine the math functions since I only need 1 and then it becomes extremely simple as I only pass the int value for the function to work on, but I thought may-hap there is a way to keep it more generic.

I do not want to use mapping of the functions I want to keep it dynamic....
is ther a way of doing so?

Comment: You mean, you want to pass a string and execute that string in the code ?

Comment: so you do not want to use `Actions` and `Func`s?

Comment: Maybe you should provide an example of how you intend on using this. Maybe there is a better way, or at least is will help us understand your needs a bit more

Comment: there is a big difference if you want "parse" a string and execute it ( like javascript eval) or you just want to pass a function design time.

Comment: You most probably want to use delegates. It's unlikely that you really need to compile a string expression in runtime.

Comment: Please provide **usage** example(s) too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to offer an alternative approach that you may not have considered.

You could use a delegate instead of passing a string; that way, you won't need any reflection.

There's a predefined delegate type in C# called `Func<>` which lets you easily define the return type and parameter types of a method that you want to pass as a delegate.

For example, the `Func<>` for `Math.Sin(double)` would be `Func<double, double>` because `Math.Sin()` returns a double and takes a double parameter.

An example will make this clearer:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            Func<double, double> f1 = Math.Sin;
            Func<double, double> f2 = Math.Cos;

            double r1 = runFunc(f1, 1.0);
            double r2 = runFunc(f2, 2.0);

            Console.WriteLine(r1);
            Console.WriteLine(r2);
        }

        private static double runFunc(Func<double, double> func, double parameter)
        {
            return func(parameter);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using http://www.csscript.net/

```
 dynamic script = CSScript.Evaluator
                         .LoadCode(@"using System;
                                     public class Script
                                     {
                                         public int Sum(int a, int b)
                                         {
                                             return a+b;
                                         }
                                     }");
int result = script.Sum(1, 2);
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are not allowed to use scripts since we did not learn scripts :(

Regardless I coudln't get it to work.
I will play around with it , as for it's a new way of thinking though I did not learn any of these tools.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the method like this:

```
public int DoCalculation(Func<double, double> func, double a)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(func(a));
    }
```

Then use it like this:

```
int result = DoCalculation(Math.Sin, 3.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In our application we use the .NET integrated C# compiler.
This is some work to do but straight-forward to implement.

[Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723558/best-practice-to-write-highly-user-extendable-c-sharp-application/17723831#17723831) with a lot more details on that.
We use this in our companies production.